# Why do I have to declare GraphicsDeviceManager in Game1 class (XNA)?

Tags: c#, xna

First of all, I am new to C# and XNA (before C++)

I've searched half the web and, I believe, entire stackoverflow, but I didn't find the answer.
In my project I wanted to create a GraphicsManager: its job will be to load/unload resources for open world game, provide more abstract rendering tools (load tileset, pick tile from tileset etc.) and so on.

That is why it felt natural to put all the graphic related objects in the GraphicsManager.

```
class GraphicsManager : Manager
{
    // provided by XNA project
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public override void Initialize(Game caller)
    {
        mainObj = caller;
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(mainObj);
    }
}

// constructor of the Game class
public Game()
{     
    Graphics.GraphicsManager.Instance.Initialize(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}
```

After some time I discovered that I need to create the GraphicsDeviceManager before Initialize(), because it will force it to call LoadContent() - I can understand that: the GraphicsDeviceManager's constructor performs some operations on the provided Game object to change its Initialize() method (or something similiar).

That is why I changed my code, so it runs GraphicManager's Initialize() in Game's constructor. Unfortunately this way it won't call LoadContent(). Why?

PS. It is enough just to declare any GraphicsDeviceManager object in the class, no need to instantiate - and then it will work. It makes no sense to me :/

@Scott W
I've deleted the `Game` constructor, renamed the class (to `Game1`) and created this method:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        Graphics.GraphicsManager.Instance.Initialize(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

But now it won't call `LoadContent`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to create a `GraphicsDeviceManager` object within a `Game` subclass. But, upon creation, it typically needs a `Game` instance (or subclass instance, e.g. `Game1`).

Usually you don't want to specify a constructor for your `Game` subclass. This is likely the cause of your problems relating to `LoadContent` not being called, etc. XNA's `Game` constructor does a few things that you're not replicating in yours, nor are you calling the base constructor. Instead of calling the base constructor, I recommend doing all that you need to do within `Initialize` or `LoadContent`; that's what they're designed for.

So take out the constructor for your `Game` class (I also recommend calling it something other than `Game` as that's what XNA's class is also called), and move initialization into your `Game` subclass's `Initialize`:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    Graphics.GraphicsManager.Instance.Initialize(this); 
    base.Initialize();
}
```

This is the standard way to create `GraphicsDeviceManager` objects within `Game` subclasses. Do it in the `Initialize` override, and do not make a constructor.

Also, I'd recommend not making a singleton for this, and simply adding a `GraphicsManager` object directly in your `Game` subclass, a basic usage of composition.